Why does using `any` as type hints cause no error?
Question
Recently I mistakenly wrote any where I should write Any. I find this does not cause any warning/error messages.
Why is this not an error?
Sample code
Environment

Python 3.12.4
IDE: PyCharm 2024.1.4 (Professional Edition)

from typing import Any

# This is just for checking if my IDE is working correctly.
def test_str() -> dict[str, str]:
    return {'one': 1, 'two': 2} # My IDE shows a message in this line.


# I don't know why this function does not have any messages on my IDE.
def test_any() -> dict[str, any]:
    return {'one': 1, 'two': 2} # This is where I expect to see a warning or an error.

# This is the function I use `Any` correctly.
def test_typing_any() -> dict[str, Any]:
    return {'one': 1, 'two': 2}




Can't find a good YouTrack issue, but this is a bug. PyCharm is just not very standard-conformant.

This answer says it all. PyCharm isn’t behaving properly in this case.
